# What is the meaning of json?

Tags: json

What is json in the world of database?

Comment: JSON isn't related to databases, but rather a format to have structured data. There are others like XML and YAML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JSON and why would I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Answer (score 4):

JSON can be used by some relational databases as a native formats. Others databases can interpret JSON and insert data into tables.

- [Microsoft SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) *(no native support, link is to parser that someone made)*
- [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26770253/3626537) *(No native support yet, link to other SO answer with some ideas)*
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) *(native support, link to manual)*

The long and the short of it, a database is usually not the best tool to consume JSON. It is done much more easily with virtually every modern programming/scripting language ever.

Answer (score 0):

> **JSON**, or JavaScript Object Notation, is a minimal, readable format for structuring data. It is used primarily to transmit data between a
>   server and web application, as an alternative to XML.

Refer: [What is JSON](http://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/)

[JSON Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: Answers are allowed on such questions?

Comment: Well if such questions are allowed then why not answer?

Comment: @Rahul Such questions aren't allowed. It just isn't closed fast enough IMHO.