# Replacing an string on a field via MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following field (which is a string) of one of my tables:

```
'[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
  {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
  {"id":"20","value":"2017/03/17"}]'`
```

As you can see, the last part, the one with `id=20` has a date on it, `2017/03/17`.

Can someone tell me how can I update that field so I can get the output `2017-03-17`?

My desired output after the update would be:

```
'[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
 {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
 {"id":"20","value":"2017-03-17"}]'`
```

If I use:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = replace(myfield , '/', '-');
```

It removes the `/` of the links, and I want to mantain them.

PS: The ids of the fields are always the same (the one for the date is always `20` for example) the only thing that changes are the values.

Comment: Then why you dont use substring operation? Search for `"{id":"20"` and then for closing `}` and fix just that substring

Comment: How can I search `"{id":"20"` with `SUBSTRING`? As long as I know for using `SUBSTRING` you need to know the position, and this varies on my fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770051/parse-json-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a query like this:

```
UPDATE  mytable
    SET myfield = CONCAT (
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield, '"id":"20","value":', 1)
        , '"id":"20","value":',
        , REPLACE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield, '"id":"20","value":', -1),'/','-')
    )
WHERE ....:
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT (
    ->     SUBSTRING_INDEX('[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
    '>  {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
    '>  {"id":"20","value":"2017/03/17"}]', '"id":"20","value":', 1),
    ->  '"id":"20","value":',
    ->  REPLACE (SUBSTRING_INDEX('[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
    '>  {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
    '>  {"id":"20","value":"2017/03/17"}]', '"id":"20","value":', -1),'/','-')
    ->  ) AS result;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
 {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
 {"id":"20","value":"2017-03-17"}] |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I knew there was an easy way, but I'm still trying to understand this. I feel this assume the `"id:20"` is the last one? Would work if there is `"id:50 http://www.sample.com"` ?

Comment: I split the string in two piece at "id:20" and change the / to - . after this i concat the first+"id:20"+replaced strin. so you can change it to everything

Comment: As I say you assume the `ID:20` is the last element. Not sure if that will always true. Check this [**demo**](http://rextester.com/CPFGZ67255)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, But you can :

1. **[split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)** the string into rows using `{` as separator
2. find the row with `"ID=20"`
3. do the replace
4. join all rows back together using `GROUP_CONCAT`

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/DBII21814)

```
SELECT  
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.json, '{', numbers.n), '{', -1) name,

  CASE WHEN INSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.json, '{', numbers.n), '{', -1), '"id":"20"') > 0 
       THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.json, '{', numbers.n), '{', -1), '/', '-')
       ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.json, '{', numbers.n), '{', -1)  
  END as result

FROM 
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers 
JOIN (
        SELECT '[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
          {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
          {"id":"20","value":"2017/03/17"}]' as json
    ) T
  on CHAR_LENGTH(T.json)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(T.json, '{', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  n
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

[**OPTION 2**](http://rextester.com/VPWDJ66082)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(json, 1, pos_begin - 1 ) as side_left,
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(json, pos_begin, pos_end - pos_begin + 1), '/', '-') as side_middle,
       SUBSTRING(json, pos_end + 1, LENGTH(json)) as side_end       

FROM (
        SELECT LOCATE('{"id":"20"', json) as pos_begin, 
               LOCATE('}', json, LOCATE('{"id":"20"', json)) as pos_end,
               T.json        
        FROM   (
                SELECT '[{"id":"6","value":["http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com","new"]},
                  {"id":"7","value":"Reuters"},
                  {"id":"20","value":"2017/03/17"}]' as json
            ) T
    ) S
;
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]